# How can I automatically update all of the filenames for my middlman blog posts after rewriting the titles?

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have a whole load of blog posts in middleman and have just worked on improving the titles, which are written in the frontmatter section at the top of the markdown file. However, the filenames are all still set to the old titles, and retyping them is a pain. Is there a quick way to either regenerate all the filenames from the current title, or get middleman to ignore the filename at build time and create a new filename for the generated HTML based on the current title?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in option that does what you need.

You would have to use your favorite language to build something quick and dirty that does that for you. In pseudocode:

- Iterate over all blog files and for each file:

  - Read the file's contents and extract the new and nice title from the front matter using a regular expression
  - Rename the file according to your desired naming scheme. You could include the original date (if present), make titles URL friendly etc.

Whether that would be more efficient than manually renaming all files it depends of course on the number of blog posts as well as you programming experience!